# Reshaping Fortran arrays

Tags: fortran

I have a huge `m by 1` array (`m` is very large) called `X` which is a result of Fortran `matmul` operation. My problem is to store this apparently 2D array into an 1D array `Y` of size `m`.

I tried with `Y = reshape(X, [[2]])` and this result some elements `NaN`. Can anyone point me to Fortran commands to do it quickly. The elements of `X` may be zero or non-zero.

Comment: Are you aware of array sections? `Y = X(:,1)` has rank 1 and shape `[m]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second argument of `reshape` (or the one with keyword `shape=`) is the shape of the function's result.  In your call, you have requested shape `[2]`.

An array with shape `[2]` is a rank-1 array with two elements.  You want a rank-1 array with `m` elements:

```
Y = RESHAPE(X, [m])
```

Now, in this case there's no need to use reshape:

```
Y = X(:,1)
```

where the right-hand side is the rank-1 array section of X.

---

When you have `Y=reshape(X,[2])`, if `Y` is not allocatable and not of size 2 then you have a problem which may indeed result in your compiler deciding---as it is quite entitled to do---to give you a few `NaN`s.

Note also that you [may not need to reshape](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51912396/3157076) your array, depending on how you intend to later use it.

Comment: With ifort, and recently gfortran, you can use map/union and treat it as either a vertor or an array... reshape does similar, and the nuance of using map/union is not really required likeit was a decade or two ago... but I still use it,

Comment: You could probably get away with adding that as an answer.  I'll keep to standard Fortran in my answer, so it would be an additional approach not covered here.